# Django - Set and use site-wide variables for use in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-apps

I'm looking for a way to set a number of site-wide (or app-wide) variables, such as website (or app) title for instance, that I would use in my templates (in my header for instance). I have something like WordPress' [bloginfo()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) in mind.

Ideally I'd like to be able to define any type of attribute at the level of a site or an app. For a given app, for instance, I'd have :

app

--attribute1 (e.g. title)

--attribute2 (e.g. contact email)

--Model1

----AttributeX

----AttributeY

----...

Meaning that "attribute1" would be unique to my app. I would then need a way to use the value of attribute1 in my templates. 
I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use site-wide (or app-wide) variables all the time using `context processors`.

Inside your app create a separate file called `context_processors.py` (needless to say that isn't mandatory to name it like that, it is just for convention) and this file must define at least one function which accepts a `request` parameter and returns a dictionary.

Something like that:

```
# yourapp/context_processors.py
# you can either use <from django.conf import settings> to make use of setting varibales

def static_vars(request):
    return {
        'var1': 'Hello',
        'var2': 'World',
    }
```

Now before you access the variables in your templates as `{{ var1 }}`, you must pass this function to the [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES) settings like this:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        # dirs here
    ],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            # some other context processors here and ...
            'yourapp.context_processors.static_vars',
        ],
        'loaders': [
            # loaders here
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Now, you can use the variables `static_vars` expose in every template.

Comment: Is there a way to hook this into the admin ? It would make sense for the site's administrator to be able to change the website's title for instance (or fix a typo in the subtitle).

Comment: I did what you proposed. But I can't see (i.e. edit) these static variables in the admin. Do I have to register them in admin.py somehow ? Sorry for these noob comments, I know noting about context processors.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood your previous comment. So, you want to set site-wide variables from within the admin, right? In order to do that then `context processors` will be of no help for you. You must create a database and store there the preffered variables. There is also a package named [`django-dbsettings`](https://github.com/zlorf/django-dbsettings/) that might help you to do that.

Comment: I'll try that then. I thought there would be a more straightforward way to make my site's main title editable though. I 'm sorry I can't mark your answer as the correct answer i this case, but perhaps I didn't phrase my question properly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have used `django-dbsettings` and its very easy to use. How else you may preserve static variables through the admin if not using a persistent storage (such as a database)? On the other hand, I think you should pick one of the answers as accepted since they both answer your initial question. If you like ask another one and be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use these variables in templates then you should look at [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). The simplest solution is to add a `context_processors.py` to your app or project and then add the path to this file to the list of context processors in your settings